# How to change cursor size in PyCharm

Tags: python

How can I change this and make it smaller??

[image]

Comment: Change the editor font size?

Comment: I think this happens when you press `insert`. Try doing that first, press the button `Ins` on your keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to help you:

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, go to `Editor` | `General (Mouse section)`.
2. Select the Change font size (Zoom) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Mouse Wheel` option.
3. Return to the editor, press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> , and using the mouse wheel, adjust the font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size to change the size of the cursor, just follow the steps :

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, go to Editor | General (Mouse section).
2. Select the Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel option.
3. Return to the editor, press and hold Ctrl, and using the mouse wheel, adjust the font size.